# How to use Thor::Shell::Basic in a Rails Generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

I am writing a Rails 3.2 generator and would like to use [Thor::Shell::Basic](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb) instance methods (e.g. `ask` or `yes?`) like they do in the [official Rails guides on Application Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates).

```
module MyNamespace
  class ScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

    if yes? "Install MyGem?"
      gem 'my_gem'
    end

    run 'bundle install'
  end
end
```

This will give me a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'yes?' for MyNamespace::ScaffoldGenerator:Class`.

I cannot figure out a clean way to make those instance methods available - I am already inheriting from `Rails::Generators::Base`.

Edit:

Ah, it probably has nothing to do with Thor... I get a warning:

`[WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/my_namespace/scaffold/scaffold_generator"`

Something is not set up correctly although I used the generator for generating generators...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, yes, it does have to do something with Thor.

Do not let yourself get confused by the warning. You know that Rails::Generators uses Thor, so walk over to [the Thor Wiki](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki) and check out [how Thor tasks work](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Getting-Started).

The rails generator execution will call any method in your generator. So make sure that you organize your stuff into methods:

```
module MyNamespace
  class ScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

    def install_my_gem
      if yes? "Install MyGem?"
        gem 'my_gem'
      end
    end

    def bundle
      run 'bundle install'
    end
  end
end
```

Be sure to put your generator into the right folder structure, e.g. `lib/generators/my_namespace/scaffold_generator.rb`.

Thanks for asking your question, dude!